# How to Compare two dates in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Can you please tell me if there is a way I can find number of days spent since a past day(please look at the code bellow). If I have a string containg a day in 2009, how can I compare it with the current day and display how many days it has been?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   string olday = "05 14 2009";
   const int MAXLEN = 80;
   char newday[MAXLEN];
   time_t t = time(0);
   strftime(newday, MAXLEN, "%m %d %Y", localtime(&t));
   cout <<"Current day is: "<<newday << '\n';

   cout <<"Days spent since olday: "<<???? << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Microsoft visual studio 2010 c++ console

Comment: Did you consider converting to e.g. `time_t` and comparing them. `time_t` is a numerical type (often something like `long`) giving the number of seconds since the Epoch (start of 1970). And one day is 86400 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to convert the olday string into something more usable. The way you do this is to create a `struct tm` and fill in the values. Then convert the struct tm to a time_t with `mktime()`, and use `difftime()` with the two `time_t` values. And convert from seconds to days.

```
//create a local tm struct
struct tm old_day ;

//since it's a local, zero it out
memset(&old_day, 0, sizeof(struct tm)) ;

//fill in the fields 
old_day.tm_year = 109 ; //years past 1900
old_day.tm_mon = 4 ;//0-indexed

//convert to a time_t
time_t t_old = mktime(&old_day) ;
```

Comment: I was looking to do something similer too, but having some problems. Could you please show it with an example?

Comment: @Paul Richter yeah, I would greatly appreciate if you could edit my code above and show it with an example. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Note, that `mktime` works with dates in range about 1970 ~ 2038, but you can use [`_mktime64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1y53h2a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which works with dates in range 1970 ~ 3000 :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use difftime.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/difftime/

Since it gives the difference in seconds, it's pretty easy to convert to days, months, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply. can you please tell me how can I make my old time("05 14 2009") equals the start variable in the example you have shown?